# On change - Remove all Screen tip from Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, office365

I have a column of hyperlinks - C column (max 38 rows) which gets imported to another column D using this formula at cell D5. Column C is hidden.

`=IF(C5="","",HYPERLINK((C5), "Click to Open"))`

**If I want to remove Screentip for all hyperlinks for each change in my content of the sheet.**

**How should I do that, the following code is not working?**

EDIT 2:

Remote the Screen Tip or just display this message in Screentip.

"Link will open in another application" Anything would help. Thank you.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D40").Hyperlinks(1).ScreenTip = " "

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to continually remove the same screen tips from the same cells every time anything in your worksheet changes?

Comment: Content is dynamic and if I change the links the screentip comes back again. So I want VBA to take care of it in the background.

Comment: There are two types of hyperlinks. There are 1) Those generated with the `=HYPERLINK(<link>, <text>)` function and 2) those generated with right-click, Link, Insert Hyperlink. They are **not** the same thing.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. But, do you know how can I display the same screentip in all hyperlinks of my excel workbook? 

Screentip: "Link will open in another application"

Comment: Generate the hyperlinks with VBA's hyperlinks.add and you can set the screen tip to anything you want.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Inserted** hyperlinks:

```
Sub ScreenTipKiller()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        h.ScreenTip = " "
    Next h
End Sub
```

This will not affect hyperlink function screentips.

**EDIT#1:**

To clear screen tips for those hyperlinks in column **1**, use:

```
Sub ScreenTipKiller()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If h.Parent.Column = 1 Then
            h.ScreenTip = " "
        End If
    Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gary's Student, can you modify only the links in column(1)?

Comment: @Gary's Student ,+1, Duh_I figured it out; Columns(1).Hyperlinks

Comment: @GMalc  See my **EDIT#1**